How to disable reCAPTCHA verification for firebase authentication in flutter(for iOS and Android)?
We are not able to disable the Recaptcha screen when authenticating using firebase.
I can see some threads but still i don't find the proper answer.Could you please suggest is it possible to Disable ReCaptcha screen ?
if yes Could you please suggest me solution ?
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/discussions/3381
